# Display all comments under a selected thread

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating an news system with comments. Everything works fine, but I have no idea how can I display the comments on a particular post.

The current code display only the 3rd comment from table **comments**

It's the comment with ID = 3, but all the other comments have $ nid = 3, so this should all be issued under the news_posts with ID = 3.

These are my SQL-Database tables:

```
TABLE news_posts (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  author VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  post TEXT NOT NULL,
  DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


TABLE comments (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nid INT(11) NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  author VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  comment TEXT NOT NULL,
  DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

This is the **news.php** which should display all posts and comments

```
$abfrage = "SELECT id, title, author, post, DATE_FORMAT(date, GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'ISO')) as sd FROM news_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start,$datensaetze_pro_seite";
 $result = $mysqli->query($abfrage)    

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

    $url = 'news/comments.php?id='. $row['id']; 

    echo '<table class="table table-bordered news"> 
           <thead> 
               <tr> 
                   <th colspan="3"># '. $row['id'] .' | '. $row['title'] .'</th>
             </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
               <tr> 
                   <td colspan="3">'. nl2br(htmlspecialchars(preg_replace('~\S{30}~', '\0 ', $row['post']))) .'</td>
                </tr> 
        </tbody> 
        <tfoot> 
               <tr> 
                   <td colspan="3"> 
                    <small>Beitrag von: '. $row['author'] .' | '. $row['sd'] .'</small>
                     <small class="pull-right"><i class="icon-comment"></i> Kommentar: <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#show_comment'. $row['id'] .'">anzeigen</a> | <a href="'. $url .'">verfassen</a></small>
                 </td> 
               </tr> 
        </tfoot> 
    </table>'; 

    $abfrage2 = "SELECT id AS comment_id, title AS comment_title, author AS comment_author, comment AS comment_text, DATE_FORMAT(DATE, GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'ISO')) AS comment_date FROM comments WHERE nid = ". $row['id'] ." ORDER BY id DESC";

    $comment_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($abfrage2) 

    $comment_stmt->execute(); 

    $comment_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_title, $comment_author, $comment_text, $comment_date))

    while ($comment_stmt->fetch()) { 
        if($comment_stmt->errno) { 
            die($comment_stmt->error); 
        } 

        echo '<div id="show_comment'. $row['id'] .'" class="comment collapse pagination-centered">
             <h4>Kommentare zu</h4> 
            <p>'. $row['title'] .'</p> 
            <div> 
                <table class="table table-bordered news"> 
                       <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                               <th colspan="3">'. $comment_title .'</th> 
                        </tr> 
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                                 <td colspan="3">'. nl2br(htmlspecialchars(preg_replace('~\S{30}~', '\0 ', $comment_text))) .'</td>
                         </tr> 
                    </tbody> 
                    <tfoot> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td colspan="3"> 
                            <small>Beitrag von: '. $comment_author .' | '. $comment_date .'</small>
                             </td> 
                        </tr> 
                    </tfoot> 
                </table> 
            </div> 
        </div>'; 
    } 

    $total_comm = $comment_stmt->num_rows;

    if($total_comm == 0) { 

        echo '<div id="show_comment'. $row['id'] .'" class="comment collapse pagination-centered">
             <h4>Kommentare</h4> 
            <div class="alert alert-info">Es wurden noch keine Kommentare zu diesem Thema verfasst</div>
         </div>'; 
    } 
} 

$comment_stmt->close();
```

I'm now trying for several days my luck, but I can't find solution to my problem.... I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: my first thought would be to try and run the sql statements on the commandline or using phpmyadmin and see if you at least get the right data from your query string. Without seeing the data table content it is hard to know for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
 while ($comment_stmt->fetch()) {
```

to this:

```
 while ($commentRow = $comment_stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
```

and continue your code from there ..

Comment: That calls an error -> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in C:\wamp\www\trier\news\news.php!

Comment: Please add a dump of your db for that record from comments table